# Partitioning any language to regular?

Tags: formal-languages

One time I saw a theorem that says something like any language can be partitioned into regular languages, but I can't remember exactly what the theorem is. 
Could somebody tell me, is this true? What is this theorem?

Comment: @Richerby, you are right, what I am looking for is a specific well known theorem; I have forgotten the resource and my question is not complete!

Comment: You might be misremembering the relevant theorem slightly. Yuval's answer shows that any language whatsoever can be partitioned into a possibly infinite collection of regular sets. The Myhill-Nerode theorem Hendrik mentioned shows that a language can be partitioned into a *finite* collection of sets if and only if the language is regular.

Comment: @RickDecker; I agree with you 100 percent,but the theorem I am trying to remember its' exact statement, has a longer proofing with some learning algorithm and iterated coded Turing machines.

Answer (score 5):

Every language can be partitioned into a countable union of singleton languages (languages of the form $\{w\}$). Since singleton languages are regular, we get that every language can be partitioned into infinitely many regular languages.

Comment: I'd like to add that if a language being partitioned is not regular then a finite partition into regular languages does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for responding ;but I was not expecting this answer, it might be something missing in my question!!. The proof I saw it for that theorem was very serious with coding and learning technique ...

Comment: @user42425 I'm not sure how coding and learning theory would fit into a question about regular langauges. Are you sure the theorem was about that?

Comment: @Richerby, The theorem about any language(with any complexity) being partitioned to regular language(s)

Answer (score 5):

Myhill-Nerode. A language $L$ is regular iff it is the union of equivalence classes of a right-invariant equivalence relation $E$ of finite index.

This is slightly more general than the statement given on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) where $E$ is taken to be a fixed equivalence $E_L$ determined by $L$ as follows: for two strings $x,y$ we have $x\,E_L\, y$ whenever, for every string $z$, $xz\in L$ iff $yz\in L$. Meaning $x$ and $y$ cannot be distinguished by extending them in the same way.

Comment: At first I looked to this theorem, but it is not what I am looking for. It should be about any language, being partitioned to regular one(s)?